# Example of an equation that generates solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, solution-verification, foliations

> Q: Is this an example of an equation that generates solutions? And is everything below correct?

**Part $1:$**

Suppose that $x$ and $z$ are independent of each other.

$$\phi(x,z)= e^{\frac{z^2}{\ln(x)}}=x,$$

where $x,z\in\Bbb C.$

$x=e^{z},e^{-z}.$

With this information I rewrote the equation as:

$\phi\big(\ln(x),x\big)=x.$

So the initial assumption that $x$ and $z$ are independent was wrong and a contradiction was reached.

Letting $z=\ln(x)\implies$ $x=x.$

In essence the whole equation is actually $x=x$ which contains all solutions.

**Part $2:$**

But $z$ could potentially act as a generator, and generate numbers to be fed into the equation. If $z$ is thought of like this, then it can be re-written as $z=\ln(s)$ which can now be thought of as accepting some parameter $s,$ and generating curves of the form: $$\phi_s(x)= e^{\frac{\ln^2(s)}{\ln(x)}}=x.$$

With the equation in this form, we can generate some solutions. So, if $s=1/2$ then the solutions are: $x=1/2,2.$ If $s=3/4$ then $x=3/4,4/3.$ And if $s=ni$ for some $n\in \Bbb N,$ then $x=ni,-i/n.$

Then the equation $$\phi_s(x)= e^{\frac{\ln^2(s)}{\ln(x)}}=x$$ is really just a subset of solutions to $x=x.$ How large of a subset, really comes down to what we choose as our set $s.$

If $s\in\Bbb N$ then we can generate the fixed point solutions to $\phi_s(x)$ like $x=e^2$ and $x=e^3$ and so on and so forth. Since we have $\ln^2(s)$ the solutions come in reciprocal pairs, i.e $( e^2$ and $e^{-2}).$

**Part $3:$**

By just looking at the function (not an equation anymore), that is, partitioning $\phi_s(x)= e^{\frac{\ln^2(s)}{\ln(x)}}$ into leaves via the generator $s\in \Bbb R^+$ we get an analytic foliation of some manifold, right? What kind of manifold?

Comment: Is $\phi_z(x)=x$ a typo in the first line?

Comment: Are you using the convention z = x+iy, or are z and x independent of each other?

Comment: $z$ and $x$ are independent of each other

Comment: notationally, it might clarify things to remap "$x$" to "$f(z)$" and then we would be looking for the function $f(z)$ that solved $\phi(z,f(z))=f(z)$

Comment: where $\phi(z,f)=e^{\frac{z^2}{ln(f)}}$

Comment: alternatively ... would it be equivalent to solve for $\Phi(z,f(z))=0$ where $\Phi(z,f)=e^{\frac{z^2}{ln(f)}}-f$