# Lifting class structures from a lorentzian manifold $\Bbb R^{1,1}$ to $\Bbb R^{1,2}$

Tags: mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

Note: $\zeta^{1,1}=\Bbb M^{1,1}$ (under a $\log-\log$ change of coordinates).  In other words, $\zeta^{1,1}$ with coordinates $(x,\phi)\in \zeta^{1,1}$ equals $\Bbb M^{1,1}$ with coordinates $(u,v)\in \Bbb M^{1,1},$ where $x=e^u$ and $\phi=e^v.$

---

> Q: How does one lift the class structures $K_S$ and $K_T$ into $\Bbb R^3$ s.t. the resulting pseudo-riemannian space $\zeta^{1,2},$ under a $\log-\log-\log$ change of coordinates, corresponds to $\Bbb R^{1,2}:=\Bbb M^{1,2}$ (2-Minkowski space)? Another equivalent way of phrasing it is: How does one project the lines of constant time and space under an orthographic projection from $\zeta^{1,2}$ to $\zeta^{1,1}?$

The main idea is that I need to be able to map $\zeta^{1,2}$ and $\Bbb M^{1,2}$ back and forth under a $\log-\log-\log$ change in coordinates.

---

Context and Background:

Define a class (space class) $K_S:=\{\phi_S(x)\}$ and a class (time class) $K_T:=\{\phi_T(x)\}$ where $S,$ and $T$ generate the respective classes: $$\phi_S(x):=e^{\frac{\ln^2(s)}{\ln(x)}}.$$ $$\phi_T(x):=e^{\frac{\ln^2(t)}{\ln(1-x)}}.$$

To understand how $S$ and $T$ generate the space see: [Example of an equation that generates solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222552/example-of-an-equation-that-generates-solutions).

With the (static, i.e. fixed background) classes generated, we can define $K_{S\cup T}:=\{\phi_S(x)\}\cup\{\phi_T(x)\}.$ We can also define $K_{S\cap T}:=\{\phi_S(x)\}\cap\{\phi_T(x)\}.$ Consider $K_{S\cap T}$.

Unpacking this explicitly, implies we can "stamp" our spacetime discretely with parametrised polynomials, $p_{s,t}(x)=x^s-(1-x)^t-$ which follows directly from equating every possible curve in each class. One can think of the "phase space" of a dynamical system if it helps.

In this view, generating our universe, [How does this Lie algebra react to this change of coordinates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571855/how-does-this-lie-algebra-react-to-this-change-of-coordinates). $\zeta$ really means defining two "phase spaces" of curves collected into two classes.

Define a new coordinate system, based on the powers of the polynomial(s). Use $(s,t)$ to represent elements in our universe $\zeta.$ [Find sequential orthographic projections, linking three different manifolds of dimension $n=1,2,3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798578/find-sequential-orthographic-projections-linking-three-different-manifolds-of-d) This puts elements in $\zeta$ in bijection with the natural numbers. This shows that initialising $\zeta$ with this coordinate system allows us to work in the countable natural number setting, and define such things as successors after defining a partial order lattice.

Using $(s,t)$ as the coordinate system with $p_{s,t}(x),$ codes $\zeta$. $(s,t)$ is a coordinate system which is more global. Penetrating down to the local coordinate system, we can look at $(x,\phi)$ which acts to code local objects in $\zeta.$ In other words the local code is embedded and parametrised by the global code.

We can also transfer this model back to $\zeta:=\Bbb M^{1,1}$ with a change of coordinates. Since $\zeta$ is defined as Minkowski spacetime in $\exp-\exp$ space. So in order to revert back to the pseduo-riemannian manifold landscape representing the backdrop of special relativity, one does $u=\ln(x)$ and $v=\ln(y).$ One can easily define lorentz boosts and the like. If this isn't clear, $uv=\ln^2(s)$ is a rectangular hyperbola with parameter $s.$ And it's implicitly assumed that the lorentz metric is being used.